# Is there a way to add a delay to your weapon following the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the game apex legends there is a slight delay to the weapon following the camera when you turn. I was wondering if there is an easy way to replicate this in unity?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, it's called weapon sway.

```
private float swayAmountX = 5;
private float swayAmountY = 2;
private float smooth = 8;

private void Update(){
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("MouseX") * swayAmountX;
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("MouseY") * swayAmountY;

    Quaternion rotationX = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mouseY, Vector3.right);
    Quaternion rotationY = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseX, Vector3.up);

    Quaternion targetRot = rotationX * rotationY;

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, targetRotation, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

*Put this in a script inside the parent of your weapon and you should be good. If you already have rotation on your character i think you can easily see how it's done and adapt it to your needs. This script stay pretty basic but you can enhance it to your liking :)*

Hope it helped you ! Have a nice day !